# How many roots are there in this equation?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I want to find all complex numbers such that
$\left| z\right|  (z-4-i)+2 i=(5-i) z$. I tried

```
Solve[Abs[z] (z - 4 - I) + 2 I == (5 - I) z, z]
```

and got

> ```
> {{z -> -1}}
> ```

This is a question in a test with multiple choice. The key of question is three numbers.

Is my commant wrong? Where is wrong?

Comment: Try `Reduce` function.

Comment: OK. I have just tried. Reduce give me 3 solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Direct solution may be obtained with `Solve[Abs[z] (z - 4 - I) + 2 I == (5 - I) z, z, Method -> "Reduce"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other ways, all very similar.

[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)
[`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html)
[`Complexes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complexes.html)

```
Solve[
 Abs[z] (z - 4 - I) + 2 I == (5 - I) z && z ∈ Complexes
 , z
 ]
```

[`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)
[`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html)
[`Complexes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complexes.html)

```
NSolve[
 Abs[z] (z - 4 - I) + 2 I == (5 - I) z && z ∈ Complexes
 , z
 ]
```

[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)
[`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html)
[`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)
(@UlrichNeumann)

```
Solve[
 Abs[z] (z - 4 - I) + 2 I == (5 - I) z
 , z
 , Method -> Reduce
 ]
```

[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)
[`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)
(@MariuszIwaniuk)

```
Solve@Reduce[
  Abs[z] (z - 4 - I) + 2 I == (5 - I) z
  , z
  ]
```

---

```
ListPlot[
 ReIm[z] /. NSolve[
   Abs[z] (z - 4 - I) + 2 I == (5 - I) z && z ∈ Complexes
   , z
   ]
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-1, 1}}
 , FrameLabel -> {"Real", "Imaginary"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]